# Custom Horizontal Progress Bar

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout

I want to create a custom horizontal progress bar that looks something like the following image:
[image: Custom horizontal progress bar]

The drawable is attached to the progress bar. There shouldn't be any space between them like in the image. Any idea how to achieve that?

Using Android and XML to create the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, then you want to make "state of the horizontal progress bar". If so, then you can look at this libraries.

- [android-stepper](https://github.com/acefalobi/android-stepper)
- [StateProgressBar](https://github.com/kofigyan/StateProgressBar)
- [Android-StepsView](https://github.com/anton46/Android-StepsView)